# LS Nav web service error while calculating basket

Tags: web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

While trying to calculate customer basket. I am getting trouble with the web service.

I tried to pass data via request and the response is a error which I don't understand.

Web Method: `WI_NC_CALCULATE_BASKET`

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> <Request>
  <Request_ID>WI_NC_CALCULATE_BASKET</Request_ID>
  <Request_Body>
    <ItemId_Type>ItemNo</ItemId_Type>
    <MobileTransaction>
      <Id>EB39ACF3-9A94-4164-A38F-E72A32BEF371</Id>
      <MemberContactNo>ACC-0003</MemberContactNo>
      <MemberCardNo>ACC-0004</MemberCardNo>
    </MobileTransaction>
    <MobileTransactionLine>
      <Id>EB39ACF3-9A94-4164-A38F-E72A32BEF371</Id>
      <LineNo>10000</LineNo>
      <Number></Number>
      <VariantCode></VariantCode>
      <UomId></UomId>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <ExternalId>195</ExternalId>
    </MobileTransactionLine>
    <MobileTransactionLine>
      <Id>EB39ACF3-9A94-4164-A38F-E72A32BEF371</Id>
      <LineNo>20000</LineNo>
      <Number></Number>
      <VariantCode></VariantCode>
      <UomId></UomId>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <ExternalId>100</ExternalId>
    </MobileTransactionLine>
    <MobileTransactionLine>
      <Id>EB39ACF3-9A94-4164-A38F-E72A32BEF371</Id>
      <LineNo>30000</LineNo>
      <Number></Number>
      <VariantCode></VariantCode>
      <UomId></UomId>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <ExternalId>10</ExternalId>
    </MobileTransactionLine>
  </Request_Body>
</Request>
```

Response:

```
<Response>
  <Request_ID>WI_NC_CALCULATE_BASKET</Request_ID>
  <Response_Code>0040</Response_Code>
  <Response_Text>Invalid Request Field  for Source MobileTransactionLine in xml setup</Response_Text>
</Response>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you shoud as your navision solution provider. This is not something like server error. The response means that you passing some parameters wrong.

Comment: @MakSim would be kind enough to tell me which parameter is incorrect here? I am really stuck to be honest!

Comment: I cant. I dont know. It is not part of the standars NAV code. It looks like some customisation been made. Only who made it can tell you was is wrong.